# Producing locale-specific short dates

Tags: c, localization

When the `strftime` C function is used under glibc and in combination with, for example, the is_IS locale, the strftime `%x` format specifier yields a string like "þri 31.des 2013", in other words, it gratuitously includes the weekday and writes the month as a word/abbreviated word. There are other locales that exhibit such behavior.

The way I see it, strftime does not offer anything for users to request a locale-specific "short date" where only digits and separators are used. Therefore, it looks like I would be required to keep a local database of locales and short date formats within my own program, mapping is_IS to "`%d.%m.%Y`" for example. Are there any additional options to consider? libicu/ICU4C?

Answer (score 1):

I reproduced your results with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <locale.h>

int
main(void)
{
   char time_buf[128];
   time_t t;
   struct tm *tmp;

   t = time(NULL);
   tmp = localtime(&t);
   setlocale(LC_TIME, "is_IS");
   strftime(time_buf, sizeof(time_buf), "%x", tmp);
   printf("time: `%s'\n", time_buf);

   return 0;
}
```

To me, this could be a bug (or at least a request to change their current behavior) that should be reported to the glibc maintainers.  I don't know what guarantees there are about what you actually get out of locale-specific `strftime` formats.  I would expect something more like the "C" locale's `%m/%d/%y` output for `%x`.  The "de_DE" locale seems to provide something like this.